# Let android app run in background

Tags: android, location, background-process

I am following the tutorial from this link : http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html.

Everything so far works fine, but I would like to let the app keep showing the current location as a toast without needing to have the app open all the time. As soon as I close the app the app stops showing the location. When I reopen the app it says "connected" and just keeps on printing the location again.

So I've looked into services but I don't really understand in how to use it. If I change the extends ActionBarActivity to extends Service the whole application is full with errors.

I've also checked other posts like : - [Running my app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20567199/3801539)
                                     - [Service run in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15494917/3801539)

But I don't really see how I can use their code to make mine work.
Do I need to have an extra class inside the mainActivity that extends from Service or how can I solve this problem.

All help is welcome.

Comment: You can not change `extends ActionBarActivity` class to `extends Service` class. You sould only move the processes which you want to do in background to the new `extends Service` class.

Comment: So the functions that should keep running should now be declared in the extends Service class?

Comment: Yes, absolutely right. Check [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

Comment: What is the first code doing? Just showing the system time once or does it keep updating it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show toast while in background i suggest you use

```
BroadcastReceiver
```

to be more logical, do code in service and call receiver to toast location
do i sound legit??

also read the service documentation, and bind the activity to the service..
[Service doucmentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) or better still read all [this](https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html)

Comment: What is the first code doing? Just showing the system time once or keep updating it?

Comment: and to what code are you referring please? @user3801539